# SQL - move date to within 48 hr window

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a bunch of historic timestamp dates. Basically, I need to simulate a new date such that the historic dates are moved to within a 48 hour window of the current date.

This is an extract of the date column:

```
2019-05-07 17:46:57.733 UTC
2019-05-15 13:03:25.247 UTC
2019-05-07 13:27:49.453 UTC 
2019-05-11 04:24:02.293 UTC 
2019-04-18 08:00:54.660 UTC 
2019-04-25 05:34:36.777 UTC
2019-05-14 16:48:07.863 UTC
```

Assuming the current date is `2019-10-03 15:00:00`. The expected range of dates should be between `2019-10-03 15:00:00` and `2019-10-01 15:00:00`

The expected results should be the following.

```
2019-10-02 17:46:57.733 UTC
2019-10-03 13:03:25.247 UTC
2019-10-03 13:27:49.453 UTC 
2019-10-03 04:24:02.293 UTC 
2019-10-02 08:00:54.660 UTC 
2019-10-02 05:34:36.777 UTC
2019-10-01 16:48:07.863 UTC
```

Comment: just to satisfy my curiosity...what's the practical use of such conversion???

Answer (score 0):

Why not just construct two days of random timestamps?

```
select timestamp_add(current_timestamp, interval cast(rand() * (60 * 60 * 24 * 2) as int64) second)
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you are looking for a random date function.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION random_date()
RETURNS DATE
AS ( DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL CAST(FLOOR(RAND() * 29 / 10) AS INT64) DAY));

with data as (
select "2019-05-07 17:46:57.733 UTC" as date_time UNION ALL
select "2019-05-15 13:03:25.247 UTC" UNION ALL
select "2019-05-07 13:27:49.453 UTC" UNION ALL
select "2019-05-11 04:24:02.293 UTC" UNION ALL
select "2019-04-18 08:00:54.660 UTC" UNION ALL
select "2019-04-25 05:34:36.777 UTC" UNION ALL
select "2019-05-14 16:48:07.863 UTC" )

SELECT 
  CONCAT(FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", random_date()), " ", SUBSTR(date_time, 12)) 
FROM data;
```

Output:

```
+-----------------------------+
|             f0_             |
+-----------------------------+
| 2019-10-01 17:46:57.733 UTC |
| 2019-10-01 13:03:25.247 UTC |
| 2019-10-02 13:27:49.453 UTC |
| 2019-10-03 04:24:02.293 UTC |
| 2019-10-03 08:00:54.660 UTC |
| 2019-10-03 05:34:36.777 UTC |
| 2019-10-02 16:48:07.863 UTC |
+-----------------------------+
```